# Function with parameter in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a function that has a parameter in which you can specify what you want to get from the function.

Example: First I would create a few shapes with the following functions:

```
circle1 :: Radius -> Shape
circle r = Shape (Circle r)

circle2 :: Radius -> Shape
circle2 r = Shape (Circle r)

rectangle :: Side -> Side -> Shape
rectangle x y = Shape (Rectangle x y)
```

Now let's say I want a function in which I can specify that I only want to see the circles, how do I create such a function? So the function would look like this:

```
getShapes(circle)
```

And the output would look like this:

```
circle1
circle2
```

Comment: Please try to give all definitions and working code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I would like to restructure your shape type:

```
data Shape = Circle {r :: Double}
           | Rectangle {l :: Double, w :: Double}
           deriving (Show)
```

Now let us think a bit about the type of your function `getShapes`, in my opinion it should have two things as input one predicate of which shapes I'd like to get back, and two from which shapes I choose, so

```
getShapes :: (Shape -> Bool) -> [Shapes] -> [Shapes]
```

would be a reasonable choice - next step - [hoogle the stuff](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28Shape+-%3E+Bool%29+-%3E+%5bShape%5d+-%3E+%5bShape%5d) and we see the second function (`filter`) seems a suitable candidate for our task.

```
getShapes = filter
```

So the remaining step is to build the `circle`-function, usually called the *predicate*.

```
circle :: Shape -> Bool
circle (Circle _) = True
circle _ = False
```

If you're new to haskell - here lies one of the most powerful concepts of haskell: **Pattern Matching**

`circle (Circle _)` checks if its argument has the type `Circle`, where type is something like constructor in an OO language. The `_` is known as *I-don't-care-variable* it is used when the name suits. So circle checks if the `Shape` it got is a `Circle` and doesn't care about the radius it has and returns `True` - OR - in any other case it returns `False`.
This would also work, if some weeks later I decided to add another `Shape` by

```
data Shape = Circle {r :: Double}
           | Rectangle {l :: Double, w :: Double}
           | Ellipsis {a :: Double, b :: Double}
           deriving (Show)
```

so now `getShape circle [circle1, ellipsis1, circle2, rectangle1, rectangle2]` should yield
`[circle1,circle2]`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
type Radius = Double
type Side = Double

data Shape = Circle Radius
           | Rectangle Side Side
    deriving (Show)

isCircle :: Shape -> Bool
isCircle (Circle _) = True
isCircle _  = False

circle1 :: Radius -> Shape
circle1 r = Circle r

circle2 :: Radius -> Shape
circle2 r = Circle r

rectangle :: Side -> Side -> Shape
rectangle x y = Rectangle x y

figures = [circle1 1.1, circle2 1.2, rectangle 1.3 1.4]

circles = filter isCircle figures

main = putStrLn $ show circles
```